# Why is the exception not being caught?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await

I think there is something missing in my understanding. If I put a breakpoint in the catch where the `Console.WriteLine` is done, it does not stop.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process(async () => await ClientMethod()).Invoke();
    Console.Read();
}

public static async Task ClientMethod()
{
    throw new Exception("Test");
}

public static Action Process(Action functor)
{
    return () =>
    {
        try
        {
            functor();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Handle exceptions ?
            Console.WriteLine("In the catch");
            throw;
        }
    };
}
```

But if I change my code into this, by removing the async behavior, the breakpoint is hit:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process(() => ClientMethod()).Invoke();
    Console.Read();
}

public static void ClientMethod()
{
    throw new Exception("Test");
}
```

Why the exception is not caught in the first case? How can I catch it?

**EDIT: I changed my code into this but it is still the same:**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var res = Process(async () => await ClientMethod()).Invoke();
    Console.Read();
}

public static async Task<string> ClientMethod()
{
    throw new Exception("Test");
}

public static Func<T> Process<T>(Func<T> functor)
{
    return () =>
    {
        try
        {
            return functor();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Handle exceptions ?
            Console.WriteLine("In the catch");
            throw;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the action in Process is being invoked as an `async void`.

Quote: from [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an
>   exception is thrown out of an `async Task` or `async Task<T>` method, that
>   exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void
>   methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an
>   async void method will be raised directly on the
>   `SynchronizationContext` that was active when the async void method
>   started.

Comment: So if I had a Func with a return value instead of an Action it should work?

Comment: I have edited my question with a Func instead of an Action, so it is no more an async void method, but the Exception is still not catched

Comment: Also take a look at this short article by the same author http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html

Comment: A short (and somewhat truncated) synopsis is that any async task runs on a separate thread and needs to handle it's own exceptions. Any unhandled exception will NOT bubble-up to the main thread exception handler. Having unhandled exceptions of this nature can cause application instability and odd behavior.

Comment: @Theo `async` methods do not in fact necessarily run in another thread.  They might run in another thread, they might do all of their work in the single calling thread, or they may *not use a thread at all* to do their work (or some combination of all of those).  The last part is also just wrong.  As this answer notes, exceptions inside the `async` method are caught, and re-thrown in various situations.  For a `void` method it's pushed to the sync context, which is likely the main thread's message loop, so it going right to the main thread's exception handler is *exactly* what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first code is that the `Action` is causing an `async void` method to be created. You should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for several reasons - one of which is that exception handling is odd (exceptions do not propagate from an `async void` method in any kind of reasonable manner).

Your second code is odd. You can see more clearly what's going on if you remember that `T` is `Task<string>`. So, your wrapper delegate is just going to return a `Task<string>`; it won't observe its exceptions. [To observe exceptions from a task-returning method, you should `await` the task it returns](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), and the code in your `try` block isn't `await`ing the task - it's just returning it directly.

The solution is to go back to the first example. What you want to do is change the `Action` delegate type to its asynchronous equivalent, [which is `Func<Task>`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html). From here, the solution flows more naturally:

```
public static Func<Task> Process(Func<Task> functor)
{
  return async () =>
  {
    try
    {
      await functor();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("In the catch");
      throw;
    }
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
await Process(async () => await ClientMethod()).Invoke();

public static async Task ClientMethod()
{
  throw new Exception("Test");
}
```

Comment: There's also no reason for the lambda to be `async` at this point, or to even have a lambda; you can just pass in `ClientMethod` as a method group, or if you *really* want a lambda, then a non-async lambda would do fine.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, but given the op's level of understanding, I didn't clean up the usage code at all.